# JAVA SWING: Unable to change text of JTextField

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield

I am working on a program to generate and solve sudoku puzzles in java using a swing gui. I am having a problem where I use the .setText() method on a JTextField but the text is not updated.

Here is my code:

main class:

```
package sudoku;

public class SudokuSolver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GUI gui = new GUI();
        gui.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

GUI class:

```
package sudoku;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Window.Type;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private Puzzle puzzle = new Puzzle();
    private Board board = new Board();
    private int[][] puzz = new int[9][9];

    // GUI Constructor
    public GUI() {

        // set up window
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("Sudoku Solver");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 300, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        // set up button panel
        JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        // set up generate button
        JButton genButton = new JButton("Generate");
        genButton.setMnemonic('g');
        buttons.add(genButton);
        genButton.addActionListener(this);

        // set up solve button
        JButton solveButton = new JButton("Solve");
        solveButton.setMnemonic('s');
        buttons.add(solveButton);
        solveButton.addActionListener(this);

        // set up board
        contentPane.add(board, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    // Button listener
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        String cmd = e.getActionCommand();

        if (cmd == "Generate") {
            // generate puzzle
            puzz = puzzle.generate();

        } else if (cmd == "Solve") {
            // solve puzzle
            puzz = puzzle.solve(puzz);

        }

        // display puzzle on the board
        board.fill(puzz);

    }

}
```

Board class:

```
package sudoku;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Board extends JPanel {

    // 9x9 board sections
    private BoardSection nw = new BoardSection();
    private BoardSection n = new BoardSection();
    private BoardSection ne = new BoardSection();
    private BoardSection w = new BoardSection();
    private BoardSection c = new BoardSection();
    private BoardSection e = new BoardSection();
    private BoardSection sw = new BoardSection();
    private BoardSection s = new BoardSection();
    private BoardSection se = new BoardSection();

    // array of sections
    private BoardSection[] sections = { nw, n, ne, w, c, e, sw, s, se };

    // Board Constructor
    public Board() {

        // 3x3 grid layout
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));

        // border
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 2));

        // add board sections to board
        for (int i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
            sections[i] = new BoardSection();
            add(sections[i]);
        }

    }

    // fill the board with data
    public void fill(int[][] data) {

        // create data sections
        String[][] nwData = new String[3][3];
        String[][] nData = new String[3][3];
        String[][] neData = new String[3][3];
        String[][] wData = new String[3][3];
        String[][] cData = new String[3][3];
        String[][] eData = new String[3][3];
        String[][] swData = new String[3][3];
        String[][] sData = new String[3][3];
        String[][] seData = new String[3][3];

        // break data into data sections
        nwData = createSection(data, 0, 0);
        nData = createSection(data, 3, 0);
        neData = createSection(data, 6, 0);
        wData = createSection(data, 0, 3);
        cData = createSection(data, 3, 3);
        eData = createSection(data, 6, 3);
        swData = createSection(data, 0, 6);
        sData = createSection(data, 3, 6);
        seData = createSection(data, 6, 6);

        // fill board section with data section
        nw.fillSection(nwData);
        n.fillSection(nData);
        ne.fillSection(neData);
        w.fillSection(wData);
        c.fillSection(cData);
        e.fillSection(eData);
        sw.fillSection(swData);
        s.fillSection(sData);
        se.fillSection(seData);

    }

    // split data into 3x3 section with 0,0 starting at x, y then convert to
    // string
    private String[][] createSection(int[][] data, int x, int y) {

        int[][] intSection = new int[3][3];
        String[][] strSection = new String[3][3];

        // break into section
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                intSection[i][j] = data[i + x][j + y];
            }
        }
        // convert section to string
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {

                strSection[i][j] = Integer.toString(intSection[i][j]);

            }

        }

        return strSection;
    }

}
```

BoardSection class:

```
package sudoku;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;

public class BoardSection extends JPanel {

    // each square
    private JTextField nw = new JTextField();
    private JTextField n = new JTextField();
    private JTextField ne = new JTextField();
    private JTextField w = new JTextField();
    private JTextField c = new JTextField();
    private JTextField e = new JTextField();
    private JTextField sw = new JTextField();
    private JTextField s = new JTextField();
    private JTextField se = new JTextField();

    // array of the squares
    private JTextField[] fields = new JTextField[] { nw, n, ne, w, c, e, sw, s,
            se };

    // Board Section Constructor
    public BoardSection() {
        // 3x3 grid layout
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));

        // border
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));

        // add all fields to the board section
        for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            fields[i] = new JTextField(1);
            fields[i].setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
            fields[i].setEditable(false);
            add(fields[i]);
        }

    }

    // Display the data on the board
    public void fillSection(String[][] data) {

        int x = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                fields[x].setText(data[i][j]);
                x++;

            }
        }
    }

}
```

I also have another class called Puzzle where there is a generate() and a solve() method that both return int[][]. I don't believe anything in it is relevant to the problem so I'm omitting it for space.

The problem is with this line is the BoardSection class:

```
fields[x].setText(data[i][j]);
```

I am not getting any error messages, however it is not updating the text. I tried replacing data[i][j] with "Z" to see if the problem was the data I was passing but it still doesn't work with just a simple string. I did however try putting the following line in the for loop that is inside the BoardSection constructor method and it DID display.

```
fields[i].setText("0");
```

Can anyone explain why it works in the constructor but not when the fillSection() method is called?

Comment: I suggest that you fire up a debugger to view the values of the variables in your code while the program is running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean to only ever fill the first field?  You never update the `x` variable to anything other the `0`?

```
public void fillSection(String[][] data) {
    data = new String[3][3];
    int x = 0; // This never changes?
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            fields[x].setText(data[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

You could try...

```
fields[i * j].setText(data[i][j]);
```

Or actually modify the `x` parameter accordingly...

**Updated...**

The other problem you're having is your shadowing the `data` variable been passed to your `fillSection` method...

```
public void fillSection(String[][] data) {
    // Oh look, I've overridden every thing
    // you just gave with my own copy of the data!!
    data = new String[3][3];
    //...
}
```

**Updated...**

Don't know if this is related or not, but it's still a problem...

You're `String` comparison is wrong...`==` is check to see if the two objects share the same memory space, which is never going to be true for `String` (in this manner)

```
if (cmd == "Generate") {
```

Instead, you should be using `String#equals` to compare the contents of the objects...

```
if ("Generate".equals(cmd)) {
```

This would mean that the `puzz` is never been updated, so when you pass it to your fields, it is probably blank...

**Updated...**

Yet another issue ;)

In your `Board` class, you are defining 9 board sections...

```
private BoardSection nw = new BoardSection();
private BoardSection n = new BoardSection();
private BoardSection ne = new BoardSection();
private BoardSection w = new BoardSection();
private BoardSection c = new BoardSection();
private BoardSection e = new BoardSection();
private BoardSection sw = new BoardSection();
private BoardSection s = new BoardSection();
private BoardSection se = new BoardSection();
// array of sections
private BoardSection[] sections = {nw, n, ne, w, c, e, sw, s, se};
```

But in you constructor, you are re-inistalition them (within in the `sections` array)...

```
// Board Constructor
public Board() {

    //...//

    // add board sections to board
    for (int i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
        // Look ma, new Board!!
        sections[i] = new BoardSection();
        add(sections[i]);
    }

}
```

This means that the `BoardSection`s `nw`, etc are never actually added to the screen...

Instead, you should simply drop those sections and use the array directly...

```
public class Board extends JPanel {

    // array of sections
    private BoardSection[] sections;

    // Board Constructor
    public Board() {

        //...//

        // add board sections to board
        sections = new BoardSection[9];
        for (int i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
            sections[i] = new BoardSection();
            add(sections[i]);
        }

    }

    // fill the board with data
    public void fill(int[][] data) {

        // create data sections
        String[][] nwData = new String[3][3];
        String[][] nData = new String[3][3];
        String[][] neData = new String[3][3];
        String[][] wData = new String[3][3];
        String[][] cData = new String[3][3];
        String[][] eData = new String[3][3];
        String[][] swData = new String[3][3];
        String[][] sData = new String[3][3];
        String[][] seData = new String[3][3];

        // break data into data sections
        nwData = createSection(data, 0, 0);
        nData = createSection(data, 3, 0);
        neData = createSection(data, 6, 0);
        wData = createSection(data, 0, 3);
        cData = createSection(data, 3, 3);
        eData = createSection(data, 6, 3);
        swData = createSection(data, 0, 6);
        sData = createSection(data, 3, 6);
        seData = createSection(data, 6, 6);

        // fill board section with data section
        sections[0].fillSection(nwData);
        sections[1].fillSection(nData);
        sections[2].fillSection(neData);
        sections[3].fillSection(wData);
        sections[4].fillSection(cData);
        sections[5].fillSection(eData);
        sections[6].fillSection(swData);
        sections[7].fillSection(sData);
        sections[8].fillSection(seData);

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed that. I added "x++;" after the setText(). Did not fix the problem however.

Comment: Fixed the shadowing problem as well, thank you. Wasn't sure what I was thinking adding that. Still didn't fix the problem though. I edited my main post with your fixes.

Comment: Boom! That last update was the issue. Everything is working now. Thank you!

Comment: Just as a hint, debugger is your friend ;)-

Answer (score -2):

Calling `setText()` only updates the *model* for the `JTextField`. In other words, the `JTextField` stores an internal String with the value which you sent it. However, the *view* (i.e. what is shown on your screen) is *not* updated. This is actually a good thing because painting is quite slow. If the UI was updated every time you call `setText()` in your Sudoku program, it would have to update 81 times.

You can force the view to update by calling `invalidate()` on any subclass of `Component`. In your situation, you probably should call `invalidate()` on the main `JFrame` or the `JPanel` that contains all of your `JTextField`s. This will cause the GUI to refresh once, rather than the 81 times mentioned before.

P.S. For more information, I suggest you research the Model-View-Controller design pattern.

Comment: First, the `RepaintManager` consolidates the repaint requests down into as few calls as possible, so you can call `repaint` as often as you like and the `RepaintManager` will decided when and how much is going to get repainted.  Second, I'm not sure your answer can hold, even in the simplest of test, calling `setText` will be updated (almost) immediately on the screen...`invalidate` only deals with the layout of the component, it's a side effect that it gets painted.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Gah! I get mixed up with using `invalidate()`...guess I need to study up on it before I answer questions like these.